# Did Robbie Williams write any songs for Take That?

Tags: pop, songwriter

The title says it all really.

Great writer is our Robbie but I'm wondering if Gary Barlow allowed him to write for Take That.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

Robin Williams is credit as writer on the album [*Nobody Else*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Take-That-Nobody-Else/release/634240) in 1995.

On the song *Sure*.

> Written-By – Gary Barlow, Mark Owen, **Robbie Williams**

Note also that when he came back in the album [*Progress*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Take-That-Progress/release/8438477) in 2010 he was credited in all songs:

> Written-By – Barlow* (tracks: 1 to 11), Donald* (tracks: 1 to 11), Orange* (tracks: 1 to 11), Owen* (tracks: 1 to 11), **Williams* (tracks: 1 to 11)**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbie_Williams#2009.E2.80.9312:_Second_stint):

> Williams explained that the long-standing feud between himself and Gary has been resolved, and how close they now were.